# Position of Kendo Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How can I determine where the appearance of the calendar kendo after clicking on the pictogram icons, so as not below or above only eg. In the middle of a div/p/span.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the DatePicker's popup position after initializing the widget like this:

```
var pickerDateViewPopup = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").dateView.popup;

pickerDateViewPopup.options.origin = "bottom right";

pickerDateViewPopup.options.position = "top right";
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: My KendoDataPicker look like this: <input class="required dateISO date-range placeholder-area" placeholder="my_text" name="data" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: data, height: 100, min: dataMin, max: dataMax }" /> it is possible to set popup position in my imput?

Comment: don't have much knowledge of angular js, may be you can use datepicker option in angular also.